# How to create simple menu?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, menu, subview

I'm trying to create simple (facebook like) menu in my app. I've found several questions, most of them had accepted answer, but usually answer is to use some programs done by developers.

These programs are often in old version of xCode (one, that didn't use storyboards) and those, that were done in storyboard, were too complicated for me to implement in my app.

So I found one question, which had as an answer something like this:
1. Create your menu view controller (UITableViewController for me)
2. Hide this controller in your initial view controller :

```
MenuViewController *menView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:menView.view];
```

3 Create a button (maybe pan gesture later), in it's method, do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
    CGRect destination = self.navigationController.view.frame;

    if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
        destination.origin.x = 0;
    } else {
        destination.origin.x +=254.5;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.navigationController.view.frame = destination;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = !(destination.origin.x > 0);
     }];


}
```

What this does I guess, it's that it basically moves your view to the right by fixed length. I suppose, that your view, that you sendedToBack (your UITableView) should be exposed and interactable. However, all it does for me, is moving top view to the right, and leaving blank black-colored screen behind.

Now I think, that my problem is either bad instantiation of menuView, or just that I understanded this guide wrong.

If anyone knows, how to deal with this, I would be very thankful for an answer. Maybe there is some already done app, that is as easy as this to understand and hopefully easier to implement in my code :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using container views in storyboard. You can size the left one how you like, then add a right one next to it, and in the inspector change its width to 320 -- most of it will go off the screen to the right, and it will resize its embedded controller to be full screen size. You can delete the view controller that you get with the left container view, then drag out a table view controller, and connect it from the left view with an embed segue (it will be the only choice when you control drag from the container view). I added two swipe gesture recognizers (one left and one right) to the main controller's view and connected them to the 2 methods in the main controller. Then in the main controller I have this code in the .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rightView;
@property (assign,nonatomic) CGRect rightRect;

@end
```

And in the .m, only this:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.rightRect = self.rightView.frame;
}


-(IBAction)revealSidebar:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        self.rightView.frame = self.view.window.frame;
    }];
}

-(IBAction)hideSidebar:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        self.rightView.frame = self.rightRect;
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: True, but that would present menu as a new view controller, am I right? I want to do facebook-like menu, where final state of presenting menu would look like this: https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/bd2a06ec982ea9d741785ce2c81b4349af59c1f4/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4168356d502e706e67 I mean I found some projects on github, that I can use to do this, but they are sooo complicated for me to understand :D In other words, I can't implement it in my project

Comment: It's hard to tell what your showing there -- it looks like the picture is cut off on the right side. Do you want something showing on the right of the menu?

Comment: Exactly, something like this -> http://mystcolor.github.com/ux/2012/01/02/the-real-benefits-on-using-facebook-or-path-liked-sidebar-navigation-in-iOS-apps/

Comment: If that's what you want, then why not use the implementation mentioned on that link? I don't think that's such a "simple" thing, as you mention in your post.

Comment: Because, modifying those source files is too much for me... I was looking for something simpler...

Comment: Basically I just want to have 2 views, one - uitableview in back and normal uiview on the front... that method I posted in question, should move my uiview to the right, so that I could see uitableview... but it isn't working as I expected

Comment: @Yanchi See my edited answer. I think this is the way to go -- it requires almost no code, and gives you 2 controllers to work with.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar, I'll give it a shot on monday (I'm off work today and don't have access to mac) and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Rdelmar, sorry that it took me so long to respond, as I had one more thing to do before I could test your solution. It looks very promising, but I have couple more questions to ask. Right now I did exactly as you advised. My problem is, that swipe gesture is left-to-right motion and Im not sure if you can revert it (so that when u swipe left to right, menu is displayed, but when u want to hide it, instead of left-to-right on menu container again, you should swipe right-to-left on right container)

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft is what dev guide says, but Im not sure where to put it

Comment: Another problem I have, is that I start with my "side menu view" rolled out.. If I cover my view controller with my "red" controller, gestures stop working... So I have it now like this http://i45.tinypic.com/rbcgg1.png

Comment: Ok I get it now... when I resize my right controller, frame gets size of it, so I cant resize my right controller then.. I'll try just manually setting rightRect in .m file

Comment: Ok after some confusion by my mistake (I connected my swipe gestures to containers but also to main view, so it was doing crazy stuff when I swiped) I only have one last question... that is, how to set my swipe gesture to work other way around (right-to-left instead of left-to-right swipe). I know I asked this before, but I spammed this with my comments pretty badly, so it may be hard to find :D

Comment: @Yanchi, just select one and change its direction in the Attributes Inspector in IB.